# Kafka - Log compaction behavior

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to understand the log compaction.

For a topic, my settings are

```
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio   0.005
segment.ms  5000
cleanup.policy  compact
```

I produced below messages to the topic

```
a   0
b   1
c   1
f   4
r   0
s   1
u   1
f   5
h   1
```

I am trying to consumer via kafka console consumer (even after waiting 5 mins and created a new console consumer) - i still see the 2 occurrences of `f`

```
a   0
b   1
c   1
f   4
r   0
s   1
u   1
f   5
h   1
```

Should it not be removed?

Comment: When log compaction occurs, you will only see the a key once. Until compaction happens, what you see is a changelog of what happens to a key. There's some parameters you can tune how often compaction occurs. Some info from Kafka - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

Comment: I started a new consumer after 10 mins. even then i saw the f twice.

Comment: @RamPrakash, how many partitions does your topic contain? Did you send all your message _at once_?

Answer (score 4):

Only messages that are not in active segment can be consider in compaction process.
Even if you set `segment.ms= 5000`, rolling new log segment can be made when new messages for partition appear.

If you send all message *at once*, all messages will go to the same segment and that segment will be active. It became valid for compaction if new messages will arrive after 5000ms. Log cleaner after `log.retention.check.interval.ms` will try to compact messages with same key.