# Speed up deletion of older records with same key (log compacted topic)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I am running Kafka broker (version 2.12) with the default server setting on my Mac. I created a log compacted topic, with the following configuration -

```
Configs: cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=1073741824,delete.retention.ms=100,segment.ms=100
```

I produced three records with same key/value. After 5 min (log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000), I read the topic from beginning. I see the following three records in the topic.  I was expecting 1 record.

```
key1:aaa
key1:aaa
key1:aaa
```

After 10 min, I produced a record with same key, different value (key1:bbb).  Then after 5 min, reading the topic from beginning results in following two records.  I was expecting 1 record (key1:bbb).

```
key1:aaa
key1:bbb
```

Is there any additional Topic configuration I need to set?  Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: My answer in another post might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430509/kafka-log-compaction-always-shows-two-last-records-of-same-key/61457387#61457387

Comment: @mikeThank you very much for providing the link, very good and detailed explanation.

Comment: Glad it helped. If it answered your question you might consider upvoting my answer and closing this question as duplicate. Otherwise let us know if anything is still unclear.